# Why is NHibernate giving me the error "could not resolve property: of: Customers"

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following table:

```
Customers:
  ID int PK
  FirstName varchar(50)
  LastName  varchar(50)
```

My mapping file: Customer.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                          assembly="Viper.DataAccess"
                          namespace="DataAccess">
    <class name="Customer" entity-name="Customers" dynamic-update="true" >
        <id name="ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="FirstName" />
        <property name="LastName" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Code snippit:

```
using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var query = from customer in session.QueryOver<Customer>()
                select customer;

    var c = query.Take(1).SingleOrDefault<Customer>();
}
```

I am getting an error of "could not resolve property:  of: Customers"

Any ideas why this is giving me this error?

Edited:

I modified my query to this:

```
var query = from customer in session.QueryOver<Customer>()
            where customer.ID >= 0
            select customer;
```

and it works fine.

Pleae tell me I don't have to have meaningless where clauses in order to get NHibernate to work!??

Comment: There should be `session.Query<Customer>()` I believe

Comment: Not according to my intellisense... am I missing a reference?

Comment: You are mixing QueryOver and Linq there. And it is completely wrong appoach. So you should add `using NHibernate.Linq;` and use session.Query<Customer>()

Comment: Could you add that as an answer so I can upvote you?  That worked perfectly!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing QueryOver and Linq there. And it is completely wrong appoach. So you should add `using NHibernate.Linq;` to your usings

And rewrite your query using `session.Query<Customer>()` instead of `session.QueryOver<Customer>()`

```
using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var query = from customer in session.Query<Customer>()
                select customer;

    var c = query.Take(1).SingleOrDefault<Customer>();
}
```